# mysql function successfully executed but not found on querying status

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql loop query as below:

```
DELIMITER $$    

DROP function IF EXISTS getTestAccounts $$;

CREATE FUNCTION getTestAccounts(endTime INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE x,y INT;
    DECLARE c1,result varchar(255);
    SET c1 = '';
    SET result = '';
    SET x = endTime;
    SET y = 4;
    sloop:LOOP
       SELECT count(*) INTO c1 FROM `accounts` where `lifeEnd` <= x;
       IF y > 0 THEN
          SET x = x-3600;
          SET y = y - 1;
          SET result = CONCAT(result,c1,',');
          ITERATE sloop;
       ELSE
           LEAVE sloop;
       END IF;  
    END LOOP;
    RETURN result;
END  $$
DELIMITER ;
```

it executed successfully. On making a

```
SELECT getTestAccounts(1368193391)
```

it show `db.getTestAccounts does not exist`

To cross check this i used

```
SHOW FUNCTION STATUS;
```

It lists up all the functions that are created long back but not the current one....

Spend almost a day not knowing where the mistake going on.....Can anyone tell me why its not been created in database... thank you

Comment: are you sure you are using database where you created function?

Comment: yah i am pretty sure... cause all the test functions that i ran to check the query are listed by STATUS function.....

Comment: Is the delimiter $$ placed correctly in line `DROP function IF EXISTS getTestAccounts $$;` ?

Comment: if it hasnt placed in the right place then it would have given the syntax error in the first instance... isnt it?

Comment: lads this query worked perfectly when i used procedures instead of functions...

Comment: The $$ ends the `DROP function IF EXISTS getTestAccounts`, so you end up with a lonely semicolon which is either superfluous or even crucial.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:

```
DROP function IF EXISTS getTestAccounts $$;
```

Delete the semicolon at the end of the line and it should work.

When executing the script as it is now, you should get an error, though.

Comment: nothing changed it executed successfully but on querying the status it showed up nothing.... :(

Comment: can you post the output you get when executing the script to create the function?

Comment: nothing specific but just this... Your SQL query has been executed successfully

Comment: can you access the DB with a real DB tool, or are you just using the local mysql client on the server? I need more info here, because when i execute this, it returns success and the function also shows up. What if you change the definer? Maybe you can create functions but are not allowed to see them?